# Oracle - Check constraint on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I am trying to add a check constraint on multiple columns in Oracle table that restricts user from inserting NULL into 3 columns simultaneously. However each column in the table can accept NULL independently but not 3 of the columns together.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_not_null 
CHECK (col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL);
```

This check constraint is not allowing NULL in any of the three columns. Any thought on this?

Comment: You may need to use a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

This constraint will not achieve your needs - it checks that all three columns are `not null`. The behavior you're describing can be achieved by negating (with the `not` boolean operator) a condition where all three columns **are** `null`:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 
ADD CONSTRAINT 
ck_not_null CHECK 
(NOT (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL AND col3 IS NULL))
```